# Error in sparseMatrix call about non-existent NA's in (i,j)

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I am using the function `sparseMatrix` from R package **Matrix**:

```r
library(Matrix)
sparseMatrix(graph$src, graph$dst, x = 1, dims = c(29, 29))
```

Here, `graph` is a data frame containing factors named `src` and `dst`, each having 29 levels.  Evaluating the call above results in this error:

```
Error in sparseMatrix(graph$src, graph$dst, x = 1, dims = c(29,  : 
  NA's in (i,j) are not allowed
```

but the fact is that neither of `graph$src` and `graph$dst` contain `NA`.  Why am I seeing this error?  How can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, we can't answer this without a [mcve]. The following works for me: `src <- factor(LETTERS[1:3]); dst <- factor(letters[1:3]); sparseMatrix(src, dst, x= 1, dims = c(3,3))`

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that you are using **Matrix** version 1.5-1 or older. Version 1.5-2 patched several bugs in the function `sparseMatrix`.  Notably, the function used to do this:

```r
    i <- as.integer(i + !(m.i || i1))
    j <- as.integer(j + !(m.j || i1))
```

with the effect of replacing factors `i` and `j` with integer vectors of equal length but consisting entirely of `NA`.  Now it does this:

```r
    if(!m.i)
        i <- if(index1) as.integer(i) - 1L else as.integer(i) # need 0-index
    if(!m.j)
        j <- if(index1) as.integer(j) - 1L else as.integer(j) # need 0-index
```

coercing to integer *first* so that factors are handled in a reasonable way.

Hence you should simply update **Matrix**:

```r
update.packages("Matrix")
```

or, if that is for some reason not possible, coerce to integer yourself:

```r
sparseMatrix(as.integer(graph$src), as.integer(graph$dst), x = 1, dims = c(29, 29))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I updated the package, but the error remained. I guess, the problem was that I was actually using another function (delta_con) that in turn used SparseMatrix. I solved by changing the code from the package, including as.integer as you suggest! Thank. you again!

Comment: Hmm ... that error message (i.e., "NA's in (i,j) are not allowed") does not exist in **Matrix** 1.5-2 and newer.  Are you sure that the update succeeded?  You could check with `packageVersion("Matrix")`.  Still, I'm glad that it is solved.  You can accept this answer by clicking the adjacent check mark.